# How to capture client host name in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

`pg_stat_activity` system view has `client_address` and `client_hostname`, but it always empty or null. Do I need to tweak anything to update the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set [`log_hostname`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-HOSTNAME) to `on` in `postgresql.conf`